# which amongst these two cases would result in memory leak

Tags: c++, delete-operator

using delete:

```
int** a=new int*;
**a=5;
delete a;
```

using delete[]:

```
int** a=new int*;
**a=5;
delete[] a;
```

To find out, I tried doing this-

```
int** a=new int*;
**a=5;
int* b=new int;
b=*(a);
delete[] a;
cout<<"*b: "<<*b;
```

getting an output- `5`

but I suspect that integer stored in b might have been deleted but not changed (no good reason to get a garbage value right ahead).

What should I do to find out (or what is the answer).

Comment: All three of your cases are Undefined Behavior, unrelated to whether or not they leak memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```cpp
> int** a=new int*;
> **a=5;
> delete a;
> ```

This is wrong, because you allocate an `int*` and don't point it to an `int` afterwards.  Accessing the `int*` itself via `*a` is OK, but accessing an `int` via the extra `*` is not OK.  This is *Undefined Behavior*.

You need to add that additional `int`, eg:

```cpp
int** a=new int*;
*a = new int;  // <-- here
**a = 5;       // <-- OK!
delete *a;     // <-- and don't forget this!
delete a;
```

---

> ```cpp
> int** a=new int*;
> **a=5;
> delete[] a;
> ```

Same problem as above - assigning to a non-existent `int` via `**a` - but worse because now you are also mismatching `new` and `delete[]`.  More *Undefined Behavior*.  You can use `delete` only with `new`, and `delete[]` only with `new[]`.

---

> ```cpp
> int** a=new int*;
> **a=5;
> int* b=new int;
> b=*(a);
> delete[] a;
> cout<<"*b: "<<*b;
> ```

Now, that is just a culmination of bad behaviors.  Not only are you:

- assigning to a non-existent `int` via `**a`
- mismatching `new` and `delete[]`

But you are also:

- leaking the `int` that you originally allocated for `b` to point to. You are re-assigning `b` afterwards with a new (invalid) `int*` value, losing access to the `int` you allocated. You have no hope of ever using a valid `delete` statement to free that `int`.
- worse, you are dereferencing `b` to access an `int` after `delete`'ing the memory address stored in the `int*` that was assigned to `b` (and that `int*` was not valid to dereference to begin with).

This code is just all kinds of *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: Great answer, Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
int** a=new int*;
**a=5;
```

You're already totally off the rails with these two lines. You allocate a new pointer to `int` that doesn't point to anything. Then you try to set the `int` it points to, but it doesn't point to any `int`.

This is no different from:

```
int *a;
*a = 5;
```

So nothing after this is going to make any sense since you've written a `5` to some random area of memory, maybe.

Comment: Can't I always reach that random area of memory by dereferencing `a`?

Comment: @AjayTyagiB18ME003 Yes, but you dereferenced `a` *twice*.